# display image retrieved as ravendb attachment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ravendb

Simple question: how to display retrieved ravendb attachment image in winforms pictureBox.

Attachment is retrieved as

```
Raven.Abstractions.Data.Attachment attachment =
                        _store.DatabaseCommands.GetAttachment("upload/"+ 9999);
```

update

Image is save with put attachment like this

```
 _Store.DatabaseCommands.PutAttachment("upload/" + attachId, null, ms,
                                            new RavenJObject
                                                {
                                                   { "Content-Type", "image/jpeg" }

                                                });
```

ms is memory stream

Comment: how was it saved? (`PutAttachment`)

Comment: @wal exactly, I updated question with PutAttachment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the attachment memory stream from the `Attachment` object:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(attachment.Data());
```

See more in [the docs](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/attachments)